# Laravel Model function to get related entities description as string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two entity relationship where Order hasMany OrderItems. I'm trying to get order item details as a description string in my desc function like below.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function desc() : string
    {
      $items = $this->items->select("item_name, price")->get();   
      $desc='';
      foreach($items as $item){
        $desc .=implode(':',$item).', ';
      }
      return $desc;
      //return 'item_name:price, cards:50,'
    }  
}
```

Its throwing

> "implode(): Invalid arguments passed"

Can you help me please how can i achive this? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: check the available methods in collections https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods

Comment: @Indra toString is throwing eception

Comment: $this->items return a collection. Check the available methods in the manual and find the one you need

Comment: or this->items->each(functiond($index, $value) { // return your logic });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be an Accessor: using get...Attribute() in your model:

```
public function getOrderItemDetailsAttribute() {
    $details= new Collection();
    foreach ($this->items as $item) {
        $details= $details->add('name: '.$item->item_name.' ; price: '.$item->price);
    }

    return $details;
}
```

Call this by:

```
order->orderItemDetails;
```

Comment: i agree, for that case better to use accessor https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: @RomanBobrik Indeed, this is a simple solution, but definitely gets the work done.
Thnx for adding the link.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your OrderItem model

```
public functon getDescAttribute()
{
    $value = "{$this->item_name}:{$this->price}";
    return $value;
}
```

This must be the best solution, $item->desc to retrieve it

Answer (score 2):

I sure that is not the best solution, but you can try:

```
public function desc() : string
{
      $items = $this->items
           ->select("item_name, price")
           ->pluck("item_name, price")
           ->all(); // here you get array with key-value pairs

      $desc = '';
      foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
        $desc .= 'item_name: ' . $k . ', price: ' . $v . ',';
      }
      return $desc;
}
```